# Как скопировать текст ошибки в monodevelop?

Tags: monodevelop

Иногда приходится переводить с английского текст ошибки с помощью переводчика. Во всплывающем сообщении нельзя выделить текст, может кто знает как добраться до текста ошибки и не писать вручную каждый раз?

Comment: А если запустить транслятор из командной строки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В панели "Текущие данные" ("Locals" в английской версии) есть стек видимых в данной области объектов, там должно находится текущее исключение (exception), вот в его свойствах есть например, Message, который легко скопировать в буфер. Запускать надо в режиме Debug.